# UIScrollView crash when I use setContentSize with auto-layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a custom UIView that I want to put into UIScrollView. I use this code:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"Case1" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(myView.bounds.size.width , myView.bounds.size.height)];
    [_scrollView addSubview:myView];
}
```

I have a crash:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view controller. INFillingHelpViewController's implementation needs to send -layoutSubviews to the view to invoke auto layout.'"

Can you help me ?

Comment: Uncheck auto layout in Case1.xib

Answer (score 0):

Why to did like this.Try these line of code.If you need any help just ask.

```
UIView *view=[UIView alloc]initWithNibName:@"view" bundle:nil];
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(myView.frame.size.width , myView.frame.size.height)];
[_scrollView addSubview:view];
```